# Does setting sharing & permissions on "Ignore ownership on this volume" disk do anything?

Tags: permission, file-sharing

I have a Mac Mini being used as a file server with an external hard drive used to store the shared folders.  If the "Ignore ownership on this volume" is **not checked**, I can control access for specific users using the System Preferences -> Sharing pane.

However, if I **check** the "Ignore ownership on this volume", all user accounts on the system (including network user accounts created with "Sharing only" option) can read/write to the shared folders over the network.  It *appears* that any sharing & permissions rules are completely ignored on this volume (which I suppose makes sense).

[image]

However, why does the system then allow me to add custom access rules to this volume?  Do these rules do anything on a volume with "Ignore ownership on this volume" enabled?

Answer (score 1):

When you set a volume to ignore ownership the kernel sets the files on that volume to the user `unknown`. Files owned by the `unknown` user appear to be owned by any user that can access those files. Still the privileges grant what you can do with any file.